# Sequential Highest High and Lowest Low in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Want to plot only 5 Highest and Lowest, Resistance / Support based on previous daily candles… it should plot previous day High Low and then the next high should be greater than previous day high. Which means, if previous to previous daily candle high is Lower than previous candle high then it will skip and then try to check condition for 3rd High candle and so on.

```
//@version=5
indicator("PHL", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500)

// Testing for now only Low values

Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low)

lline = line.new(bar_index, Low, bar_index+1, Low, extend = extend.right, color=color.red)

l2LimitInput = input(5) 
var l2Array = array.new_line()
array.push(l2Array, lline)

if array.size(l2Array) > l2LimitInput
    firstLine =array.remove(l2Array, 0)
    line.delete(firstLine)
```